# How to limit checkbox selection to one using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

How to limit checkbox selection to one using jquery or javascript  and other checkbox should be disabled after one checkbox selected?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="size" value="Small" />Small
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="size" value="Medium" />Medium
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="size" value="Large" />Large
<input type="checkbox" name="size[]" id="size" value="Xl" />XL
```

**Here The Example But I Want Same Thing In Html Or Php**

```
http://gravitywiz.com/demos/limit-how-many-checkboxes-can-be-checked/
```

**Problem Is Solved Now Here The Final Solution**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
}else{
$inputs.prop('disabled',false);
}
})
})
</script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"> 
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" />
```

Comment: If you only want one selected, why not use radiobuttons instead?

Comment: Edit: what @icanc said

Comment: @icanc checkboxes is better then radio?

Comment: It's not that one is better than another, they serve a different purpose.

Comment: Are you developing an app to show some students how *not* to do UX?!

Comment: @edgematrix Checkboxes are normally used to allow selection of multiple items and radiobuttons are purposed to do the opposite.  So in your case using checkboxes seems to be adding extra work.

Comment: Also, all your IDs are the same. This is incorrect.

Comment: @icanc i got the example but is written on the `asp <br> http://gravitywiz.com/demos/limit-how-many-checkboxes-can-be-checked/`

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").on("click" , function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").not(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

## [Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tHUdS/1/)

Comment: even what about if uncheck checkbox then it should enable again others checkboxes?

Comment: @edgematrix Sure, let me add that in.

Comment: @edgematrix Great, so is there anything else you need or are you all set?

Comment: @Evan script working only on the jsfiddle not working in the html page?
`http://jsfiddle.net/ZB8pT/`

Comment: @edgematrix Well, I don't have your html page, I only have the details you've provided me with

Comment: @edgematrix make sure it is wrapped in $(document).ready(function(){//rest of code});

Comment: @evan i'm taking about this page `http://jsfiddle.net/ZB8pT/` is working on the `jsfiddle` when i copy script and paste into the blank html page for the demo then it is not working in the html ?

Comment: @edgematrix You need to include the jQuery script

Comment: @edgematrix It's not included in the example you just sent me .... You need to include jQuery (the actual library). You can get it from google.

Comment: @edgematrix Include this at the top of the page in the `<head></head>` tags:

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @evan it is already included `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @evan sure if i will get more reptution so definely i will mark your answer now i got another problem here the question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048943/how-do-i-use-multple-jquery-version-on-the-single-page

Comment: Evan, you deserve a Purple Heart for this one... Jeebus.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable, user can't change his choice after first selection. 
Here is a radio button behavior for checkbox.

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on('click', function() {   
    $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).attr('checked', false);  

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BxF4Y/

But to doing that, the best way is to use radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Browsing the source code of that page reveals the jQuery they used to achieve that effect. You should just be able to change the checkboxLimit to 1.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $.fn.checkboxLimit = function(n) {

        var checkboxes = this;

        this.toggleDisable = function() {

            // if we have reached or exceeded the limit, disable all other checkboxes
            if(this.filter(':checked').length >= n) {
                var unchecked = this.not(':checked');
                unchecked.prop('disabled', true);
            }
            // if we are below the limit, make sure all checkboxes are available
            else {
                this.prop('disabled', false);
            }

        }

        // when form is rendered, toggle disable
        checkboxes.bind('gform_post_render', checkboxes.toggleDisable());

        // when checkbox is clicked, toggle disable
        checkboxes.click(function(event) {

            checkboxes.toggleDisable();

            // if we are equal to or below the limit, the field should be checked
            return checkboxes.filter(':checked').length <= n;
        });

    }


        $("#field_11_1 .gfield_checkbox input:checkbox").checkboxLimit(3);


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an old thread, however there is no real conclusion here. I have included a fiddle with my version of how check-boxes should work should you wish to limit the number of boxes checked by the user.

```
/** Begin HTML **/
<div class="cContainer">
<div class="cDropdown">
    <div class="downArrow"></div>
    <h4>Night Life</h4>
</div>
<div class="multiCheckboxes stick">
    <input id="1" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="1" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="1">Dive Bar</label>
    <br>
    <input id="2" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="2" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="2">Pub</label>
    <br>
    <input id="3" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="3" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="3">Dance Club</label>
    <br>
    <input id="4" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="4" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="4">Pool Hall</label>
    <br>
    <input id="5" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="5" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="5">Karaoke</label>
    <br>
    <input id="6" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="6" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="6">Sports Bar</label>
    <br>
    <input id="7" class="stick" type="checkbox" value="7" name="l-28">
    <label class="stick" for="7">Trendy</label>
    <br>                    
</div>
```

/** END HTML **/

/** BEGIN JS **/

```
$('.cDropdown').on('click', function (e) {
$('.multiCheckboxes').slideUp(50)
e.stopPropagation();
currentDrop = $(this).next();
currentDrop.stop().slideToggle();
});
$('input:checkbox[name="l-28"]').on('change', function () {
var nightLifeLimit = $('input:checkbox[name="l-28"]:checked').length;
    if (nightLifeLimit == 2) {
    $('input:checkbox[name="l-28"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            return;
        }
        else {
            $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
}
else {
    $('input:checkbox[name="l-28"]').each(function () {
        $(this).prop('disabled', false);
    });
  }
});
```

/** END JS **/

/** BEGIN CSS **/

```
.cDropdown {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 2px inset #D3D3D3;
    clear: right;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    width: 150px;
}
.cDropdown h4 {
    font-size: 0.86em;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 0 0 0 1px;
    padding: 0;
}
.downArrow {
    border-left: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-right: 8px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-top: 8px solid #3C3C3C;
    float: right;
    height: 0;
    margin: 3px 0 0 3px;
    width: 0;
}
.multiCheckboxes {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid #3C3C3C;
    display: none;
    left: 9px;
    max-height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    width: 146px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.multiCheckboxes label {
   float: none !important;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    width: 7.6em !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/defmetalhead/9BYrm/1/