# how do i use multple jquery version on the single page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I use multiple jquery version on a single page? I have two different jquery version and both are necessary for different functions but both versions are conflicting each other.if i will use `jquery noconflict` then `products scripts` won't be work?

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
oldjq = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script> 

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

**Jquery 1.9.1 Need To Run This Script**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); 
}else{
$inputs.prop('disabled',false);
}
})
})
</script>

<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox"> 
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox">
<input type="checkbox" />
```

**Jquery 1.4.2 Need To Run These Scripts**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/banner_pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/light_box.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/jquery.mix.js"></script>
```

**Problem is Solved Now Here THe Final COde**

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input:checkbox').click(function(){
var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
if($(this).is(':checked')){
$inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
}else{
$inputs.prop('disabled',false); // <--
}
})
});
})(jQuery);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"  
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/menu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/banner_pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/light_box.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/cloud-zoom.1.0.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/jquery.mix.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sounds messy! But here's a possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566595/can-i-use-multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

Comment: @showdev not possible duplicate both are different question?
please read it what i asked 
`How do I use multiple jquery version on a single page? I have two different jquery version and both are necessary for different functions but both versions are conflicting each other.if i will use jquery noconflict then products won't be work?`

Comment: Oh, you don't want to use `noConflict`. In that case, you might be out of luck. It's impossible for two jQuery references to be separate but also not separate.

Comment: Why not just amend the code which requires jQuery 1.9.1 so that it works with jQuery 1.4.2? It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: If you can identify which scripts are not working with the new jQuery, you can probably find updates or alternatives that will. For example, `cloud-zoom` 3.0 works with jQuery versions 1.4.3 - 1.9.1.

Comment: In reference to your update with the solution I have to ask, why force the user to download jquery twice?

Answer (score 5):

Since it's only a few lines of code, I would suggest amending the chunk which requires jQuery 1.9.1 so that it works with jQuery 1.4.2

I've updated it below to work with jQuery 1.4.2. I use the `attr` method rather than `prop` to manipulate the `disabled` property (you can check the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to see if this is likely to cause any issues). This solution avoids running two instances of jquery and avoids having to find updated versions of all the libraries / plug-ins you're already using.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:checkbox').click(function(){
        var $inputs = $('input:checkbox')
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            $inputs.not(this).attr('disabled',true); 
        }else{
            $inputs.attr('disabled',false);
        }
    })
})
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NE7K2/).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, after you load your first version, do this

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Load your second version of jQuery.

Refer to the first version with `$j` and the second as `$`

Comment: Well assuming the code wasn't designed for two versions, some refactoring will be necessary. This is simply the way to work with two different versions of jQuery.

Comment: You should use $ for later scripts and $j for earlier ones, then it will work.

The technical solution is simple, but you are wrong in the premise - you don't need two jQuery instances, you just need to learn more.

Comment: @edgematrix You will have to modify one or the other to reference the new `$j`. Might be easier to either to modify the first block to work with the older version of jQuery, or modify your products scripts to work with the newer version of jquery.  This is common place with jquery: 1)Jquery has new things you want to use.  2)You have to decide whether the new things are worth upgrading and testing+fixing old code to work with newer version of jquery. I would advise against trying to support two different versions of jquery. Fix your old code, or do without the newer features.  Just my opinion.

Comment: @Richard +1 for not needing two instances. Better off consolidating and updating old scripts as necessary to make them all work with the same jQuery instance.

Comment: @richard any kind of example?

Comment: @edgematrix `$(document).ready(function () {` -> `$j(document).ready(function () {` and same for all other jquery $ in that first code block.  Not sure that's the example you wanted.  Going the better route of fixing old code, we don't have enough information to help you there.  You will need to troubleshoot, step through code and identify what deprecated features you are using in the old code.

Comment: You mean example how to use two jQuery instances on one page, or example how to learn more javascript?

Comment: @Richard i have posted the code but i'm confused on it please help me thanks

``

Comment: Look to net.uk.sweet - he posted correct solution. If you don't want to refactor legacy code to new jQuery (and it is easy, I have done it many times), just keep your new code compatible with 1.4, that's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is one possible solution - you could bind new version of jQuery to the closure.
But my advice is DON'T DO THAT, it is like shooting yourself to your own leg.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
// Jquery 1.9.1 Need To Run This Script:
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function ($) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // code that uses jQuery 1.9.1
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>

// ...

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
//Jquery 1.4.2 Need To Run These Scripts:
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="products2/js/common.js"></script>
// ...
```

Comment: Why is it like shooting yourself in the leg?

Comment: Because in long term, it causes much more trouble. There are two correct solutions: refactoring or writing new code with old API. Both are less risky and not so difficult.

Comment: I'm not challenging you, just interested. I thought there might be some fundamental issue with the approach which you've suggested which I didn't understand. So is the trouble you identify over the long-term simply issues with maintaining two versions of jquery?

Comment: Not only. The main issue is confusion, because you need to keep track, which code uses which API. This usually leads to quite nasty bugs that are hard to spot and repair.

Comment: @richar can you tell me now how do i use this script with` 
if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable all but checked one
    }else{
    $inputs.prop('disabled',false);`

`$('input:checkbox').screwDefaultButtons({
image: 'url("images/checkboxSmall.jpg")',
width: 43,
height: 43
});
`

Comment: Oh sorry, I had a wrong comment there, i fixed it, is it now clear? You place the code with new API to the inline javascript block (replace the comment "code that uses jQuery 1.9.1")